# Scrapy output to CSV from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I have finished a pipeline and the spider everything through the jupyter notebook.
I think it scrapes everything correctly (runs fine) , but I have specified that it creates a CSV file with the outcomes on my desktop but doesn't work for some reason. 
I thought it would work using FEED_URI, but it looks like it didn't. I am sure I am missing something but can't figure out where.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import logging
from datetime import date
from scrapy import signals


class BBPipeline(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.file = open('/Desktop/bbdata.csv', 'w+b')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item


class BBItem(scrapy.Item):
    date = scrapy.Field()
    promo = scrapy.Field()



class BBSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bb"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/kaged-muscle/in-kaged.html?skuId=KAG3460042',
        'https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/kaged-muscle/in-kaged.html?skuId=KAG4690241'
    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': '/Desktop/bbdata.csv','ITEM_PIPELINES':{'bb.pipelines.BBPipeline':300},'FEED_FORMAT':'csv'}

    def parse(self, response):

        item = BBItem()
        item['date'] = date.today()
        item['promo'] = response.css('article > div > section.col-sm-4 > div > form > div.sku-chooser__info > div  > span.vio-text--vio-green ::text').extract()
        yield item



process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(BBSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the paths of your csv files to absolute paths
Example

```
C:/your/path
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks that was an example to not put my real path but I have put the path from the terminal (i use a mac) (still not working)